# URL da rota sendo montada incorretamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, route

Estou com um projeto em asp.net mvc 4, usando [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) para montar as rotas, e estou verificando um comportamento estranho.

Ao montar os meus actions de GET e POST nessa ordem:

```
    [GET("editar/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Editar(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [POST("salvar-edicao")]
    public ActionResult Editar(string teste)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

O endereço do meu form fica da seguinte forma:

```
<form action="/editar/1" method="post"> <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Fazendo com que ele não faça o post para o local correto, me retornando 404. Entretanto, se eu inverter a ordem dos dois métodos, colocando o POST como primeiro, o endereço do form é montado corretamente, mas o link para chamar o get não:

```
    [POST]
    public ActionResult Editar(string teste)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [GET("editar/{id?}")]
    public ActionResult Editar(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

form:

```
<form action="/Editar" method="post">
```

link:

`@Html.ActionLink("Teste", "Editar", "Home", new { id = 1 }, new { })`

montado assim

`http://localhost/Editar?id=1` ao invés disso `http://localhost/Editar/1`

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por que você não utiliza a mesma action como GET/POST?

Comment: Esse foi só um exemplo, mas talvez seja um problema pq toda a aplicação está modelada dessa forma. Como seria utilizando a mesma action para GET/POST?

Comment: public ActionResult Editar(int id)
    {
          if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)){ //Edita } else { //nao edita }

        return View();
    }

Comment: Tenta alterar o `[POST]` para `[HttpPost]`

Comment: O [POST] é do AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc, eu posso adicionar o [HttpPost], mas o comportamento vai ser idêntico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente para o formulário ser postado corretamente utilizando atributerouting, os métodos devem possuir rotas idênticas.

```
[POST("editar/{id}")]
public ActionResult Editar(Pessoa teste)
{
    return View();
}

[GET("editar/{id}")]
public ActionResult Editar(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Dessa forma os links e os formulários são montados e respondem corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

`Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Editar(int id)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(string teste)
{
    return View();
}
```

Na sua `View`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   <input type="text" id="teste" />
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
}
```

E para gerar o `link`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Teste", "Editar", "Home", new { id = 1 }, null)
```

Comment: Olá, Diego. Dessa forma ele continua a montar o form da maneira que mostrei acima, fazendo com que o action do post não seja localizado no controller.<form action="/editar/1" method="post"><input id="teste" name="teste" type="text" value="" /><input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

Comment: @tparesque, nunca mexi com o `AttributeRouting`, mas pelo que eu entendi ele força a entrada no `Get`, se você retirar o `[GET("editar/{id}")]`, irá funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o roteamento está sendo gerado errado pois você está usando as duas ´actions´ com o mesmo nome, apenas mudando o tipo de dado, porem ao gera o roteamento o tipo do dado recebido não é observado para gerar a rota.

Acredito que se você fizer o seguinte irá funcionar:

```
[GET("editar/{id}")]
public ActionResult Editar(int id)
{
    return View();
}

[POST("salvar-edicao")]
public ActionResult Editar(int id, string teste)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Olá, @Richard Dias. Bem observado, fiz aqui o teste, mas o form continua sendo montado da mesma maneira... Será que é um bug do attributeRouting? Pq se essa mesma abordagem nativa do asp.net mvc funcionaria corretamente apenas com [HttpGet] e [HttpPost], entretanto, customizar as rotas com esse framework é uma premissa do projeto.